# String.length() gives me a wrong value

Tags: java, string, if-statement, try-catch, string-length

Whenever I enter a password under 10 characters it gives me `Password cannot exceed 10 characters`.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String name = Name.getText();
        String Username = uName.getText().toString();
        String Pass1 = uPass.getPassword().toString();
        String Confirm = uConfirm.getPassword().toString();
        String Status = "OFFLINE";
        int PassLen = Pass1.length();

        if (Username.equals("") || Pass1.equals("") || Confirm.equals("") || name.equals("")) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot leave any fields blank when creating an Account. Please Try Again");
        } 
        else if ((uPass.getPassword().toString()).length()>10)
        {
            uPass.setText("");
            uConfirm.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password cannot exceed a maximum of 10 characters.");  
        }
        else if (!Pass1.equals(Confirm))
        {
            uConfirm.setText("");
            lblError1.setText("Passwords Do Not Match.");
            lblError2.setText("Please re-enter your Password.");
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                DB_Connect connect = new DB_Connect();
                ResultSet rs = connect.queryTbl("SELECT * FROM ACOUNTS");
                boolean AlreadyUser = false;
                String User;
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    User = rs.getString("Username");
                    if(Username.equals(User))
                    {
                        AlreadyUser = true;
                    }
                }
                if (AlreadyUser==false)
                {
                    connect.updateTbl("INSERT INTO NBUSER.ACCOUNTS (USERNAME,PASSWORD,STATUS,NAME)VALUES ('"+Username+"','"+Pass1+"','"+Status+"','"+name+"')");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Created Successfully !");
                    this.dispose();
                    new Topics().setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username you have selected already exists. Please select a different Username");
                    uPass.setText("");
                    uConfirm.setText("");
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CreateAccount.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: What does `uPass.getPassword()` return? Perhaps it returns an instance of some class whose toString method doesn't return the password String.

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of your objects to see what the *actually* contain?

Comment: Open your debugger and display the value of `uPass.getPassword().toString())`

Comment: Also, why are you using `uPass.getPassword().toString()` when you could just have used `Pass1`. Remember, DRY.

Comment: What `uPass.getPassword()` returns ?

Comment: If getPassword() returns a `char[]`, the proper way to turn it into a string is `String(getPassword())`, as far as I'm aware, not `.toString()`.

Comment: Comment on code quality. Not only do you constantly violate DRY (dont repeat yourself), but SLR (single layer of abstraction) and SRP (single responsibility principle). Long story short: consider also learning how to write good code. The perfect resource to get started on that is "Clean code" by Robert Martin; which you can find on the internets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're obviously using Swing, it is also very likely that you use a [`JPasswordField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) for your passwords. So let's see, what [`getPassword`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword--) really does:

> `public char[] getPassword()`
>
> Returns the text contained in this TextComponent. If the underlying document is null, will give a NullPointerException. For stronger security, it is recommended that the returned character array be cleared after use by setting each character to zero.
>
> **Returns:** the text

As you can see, it returns your password in a `char[]` and since this class doesn't override `toString` your call of `uPass.getPassword().toString()` results in something like:

> [C@1d44bcfa

which is the result of calling [`Object#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

The length of this String is 11 and therefore larger then 10 and your `else if` block (`else if ((uPass.getPassword().toString()).length()>10)`) will be entered.

To fix that, call the `String` constructor [`String(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-) like:

```
String Pass1 = new String(uPass.getPassword());
```

---

Please use this just as a "quick fix" for your current problem and try to find a way to use the originally returned `char[]`. As mentioned by the quoted JavaDoc it is recommened the "clean" the char array after using it, so the password won't be stored there anymore. By creating a String from the array, using `new String(uPass.getPassword())`, you're creating *another* object in the heap which contains the password and which also needs to be removed from there. So it would add more work for you.

Comment: The part about "having the password" in the stack is inaccurate in the context of Java. Even in other languages, the scope of a variable does not necessarily dictate the location in which its contents are stored (e.g. stack or heap in C/C++).

Comment: Thank you so much! Very quick response time!

Comment: @ray Yes, it depends on the type. I removed that part.

Comment: @Tom: It does not depend on the type. It depends on whether the `new` operator is used or not. The last part of your post is still inaccurate.

Comment: @ray Right, because `new String(uPass.getPassword())` doesn't use the `new` operator.

Comment: @Tom: `getPassword` returns a `char[]`. The `char[]` will have been allocated using the `new` operator, which means it's in the heap. For all practical purposes, all Java objects are stored in the heap. (If it isn't, it's a JVM optimization/implementation detail that no one should assume or rely on. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991701/is-a-string-literal-stored-on-the-stack-is-a-new-string-stired-on-the-stack))

Comment: @ray I haven't denied that. What I said is that he shouldn't create an additional (even though I omitted that specific word) object in the heap with this password.

Comment: @ray I've updated the answer to explain a bit more detailed what I mean. I hope it won't cause more misunderstandings.