# How is the memory allocated(stack and heap reference) when an OBJECT array is created?

Tags: java

like

```
public static student[] arr = new student[10];
```

now,  student is a class with some instance variables `name(String)` and `age(int)`.
I wanna know that as soon as this line is executed what will happen??
Will all the ten references get memory or I have to allocate them individually?? What if tried to access `student[5].age`?
I need to know the memory allocation status.. Thank You...............

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: but I cant see the memory allocation thing :(

Comment: Whether an object is *ever* stored on the stack is in general hard to determine. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787611/why-does-java-uses-heap-for-memory-allocation

Answer (score 3):

When the above statement is executed, JVM will create 10 contiguous memory location, each big enough to hold reference to `student`. This array, however, will contain no references or `null` if you will. When you execute statement like `arr[0] = new student();` a `student` object will be created on heap and its reference will be saved in `arr[0]`. Remember that the array is also allocated on heap.

So once you have create 10 `student` objects, each will be allocated somewhere on the heap but their references will be stored in `arr`

Comment: u mean to say that stack won't do anything in this?

Comment: In your case no. Stack will only be used when you are using local variables (including arguments). For e.g. you have String a = new String("abc"). Now their are two things here. The variable 'a' will be created on stack but it will only hold reference to a string "abc" that is created on heap. So you have a string "abc" in heap whose reference is saved in a local variable 'a' on stack.

Comment: maybe this can clear up things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991701/memory-allocation-in-java-heap-or-stack

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
public static student[] = new student[10];
```

As soon as that line executes ,`JVM` allocates memory for 10 student `references`.

From [official docs on Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), look at the flow.

```
  // declares an array of integers
        int[] anArray;

        // allocates memory for 10 integers
        anArray = new int[10];

        // initialize first element
        anArray[0] = 100;
```

Comment: dumb question from almost a year later: after anArray = new int blah, what would the array be filled with, since primitives can't be null?

Comment: @hintss Answer after 2 year. For primitives, their array will be initialized with their default value.  Default value (if nothing is assigned to it) for objects is null. Default value for integer is 0.

Answer (score 2):

**Only reference variables will be created**, when you create an array of objects. In your case reference variables for student class.

In the following image, a set of reference variables are created. Then, you can
point those reference variables to actual objects, later.

[image: Dog object array]

Comment: What book is that from?

Comment: I read the book when i was appearing for oracle java certification. http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060

Answer (score 1):

`public static student[] arr = new student[10];` will allocate the memory for 10 students. These memory are filled with null.

So here you cant access `student[5].age` because the reference to the actual object doesn't exist.

We need to create the Object reference individually like below

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   student[i]= new Student();
 }
```

if you are accessing student[5].age before creating the actual object reference you will end with NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

> Will all the ten references get memory or I have to allocate then individually?

You will get space for ten references. Those references will be initialized to `null`. If you want them set to anything other than `null`, you'll have to do it separately.